# 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch a quote from the an api https://type.fit/api/quotes but it's not showing and its show me the this error: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

This is the model class for the json:

```
class Autogenerated {
  String text;
  String author;

  Autogenerated({this.text, this.author});

  factory Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Autogenerated(
        text: json['text'],
        author: json['author'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['text'] = this.text;
    data['author'] = this.author;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now this I use the called this `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`
and now I used the `http.get` to call the api like this:

```
    final response =
  await http.get('https://type.fit/api/quotes');
```

here is the full code of it...

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quotes_season/modal.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Quote extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuoteState createState() => _QuoteState();
}

Future<Autogenerated> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('https://type.fit/api/quotes');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Autogenerated.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class _QuoteState extends State<Quote> {
  Future<Autogenerated> futureAutogenerated;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAutogenerated = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchAlbum(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.title));
            }else if(snapshot.hasError){
              return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}"));
            }

            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site that you posted returns a `List` of what you modelled in your code as `Autogenerated`. Based on the rest of your code it seems you only want one of these `Autogenerated` objects, so you can just say to use the first index in the `List` that you retrieve.

```dart
Future<Autogenerated> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('https://type.fit/api/quotes');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    List parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);
    return parsedJson.isNotEmpty ? Autogenerated.fromJson(parsedJson[0]) : null;
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want you want to display all of quotes you can parse that and return a list of `Autogenerated`, but this would involve changing more code in displaying all of the quotes.

```dart
Future<List<Autogenerated>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('https://type.fit/api/quotes');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    List jsonList = json.decode(response.body);
    List list = jsonList.map((elem) => Autogenerated.fromJson(elem)).toList();
    return list;
  }
  ...
}
```

```dart
class _QuoteState extends State<Quote> {
  Future<List<Autogenerated>> futureAutogenerated;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAutogenerated = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: futureAutogenerated,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data.length, itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("${snapshot.data[index].text}, ${snapshot.data[index].author}"));
            }else if(snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}"));
            }

            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Full Working test code example - this should be used only as a proof of concept, you will need to implement this into your existing code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home:Quote()));
}

class Quote extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuoteState createState() => _QuoteState();
}

Future<List<Autogenerated>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('https://type.fit/api/quotes');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    List jsonList = json.decode(response.body);
    List list = jsonList.map((elem) => Autogenerated.fromJson(elem)).toList();
    return list;
  }
  else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class _QuoteState extends State<Quote> {
  Future<List<Autogenerated>> futureAutogenerated;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAutogenerated = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: futureAutogenerated,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data.length, itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("${snapshot.data[index].text}, ${snapshot.data[index].author}"));
            }else if(snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}"));
            }

            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
    );
  }
}

class Autogenerated {
  String text;
  String author;

  Autogenerated({this.text, this.author});

  factory Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Autogenerated(
        text: json['text'],
        author: json['author'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['text'] = this.text;
    data['author'] = this.author;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218551/discussion-on-answer-by-christopher-moore-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-ty).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fetch JSON list from the API endpoint, but your parsing code is parsing single JSON object.

Your method has to change to return list of objects:

```
Future<List<Autogenerated>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('https://type.fit/api/quotes');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    List jsonList = json.decode(response.body)
    List list = List.generate(jsonList.length, (i) => Autogenerated.fromJson(jsonList[i]));
    return list;
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

After this change of the API call, your state class should look like this:

```
class _QuoteState extends State<Quote> {
  Future<List<Autogenerated>> futureAutogenerated;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAutogenerated = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: futureAutogenerated,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              List<Autogenerated> list = snapshot.data;
              Autogenerated firstItem = list[0];
              return Center(child: Text(firstItem.text));
            }else if(snapshot.hasError){
              return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}"));
            }

            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

If your goal is to create a list of elements, and not a single element, you would need to modify widget being used:

```
return Center(child: Text(firstItem.text));
```

and do something like this instead:

```
List<Autogenerated> list = snapshot.data;
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(list[index]),
);
```

Comment: @UchennaNdukwe you would need to modify your FutureBuilder part of the code, to read snapshot.data as a list, and not as an object that contains field title. Try parsing actual data within FutureBuilder and this will work.

Comment: pls explain more @Aleksandar

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the line calling snapshot.data and look in the debugger what object type that property is. It is no longer Autogenerated class, but List<Autogenerated>. Therefore, your Center widget, holding Text child widget has to be modified in order to support new logic.

Comment: i just editted it but am getting errors like: List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type FutureOr<List<Autogenerated>>

Comment: Please check out my updated answer for more details on how to parse received data through snapshot property of FutureBuilder.